# Restkit: methodSignatureForSelector crashing in RKMappingOperation with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: restkit-0.20

In the file RKMappingOperation there is method

```
- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    return [self.object methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
}
```

which triggers exception on iPhone5 but the application continues to run. But on iPhone4S the application crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

[image]
[image]

I assume the exception is handled as stated in the documentation:

*Raises NSInvalidArgumentException. Override this method in your concrete subclass to return a proper NSMethodSignature object for the given selector and the class your proxy objects stand in for.*

The log file:

```
T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:862 Performing mapping operation: <RKMappingOperation 0x181e1960> for 'TSNDecimal' object. Mapping values from object 10 to object <TSNDecimal: 0x18004bc0> (entity: TSNDecimal; id: 0x1819dcb0 <x-coredata:///TSNDecimal/t507A4693-CB2E-4194-966A-00BA8AD5CC70391> ;
    data: {
    number = 0;
    responseName = nil;
    sortId = 0;
    ticket = nil;
}) with object mapping (null)
2014-07-07 13:17:50.194 VZN Mobile[440:8f0f] D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:131 Cached property inspection for Class 'TSNDecimal': {
number =     {
    isPrimitive = 0;
    keyValueCodingClass = NSDecimalNumber;
    name = number;
};
responseName =     {
    isPrimitive = 0;
    keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
    name = responseName;
};
sortId =     {
    isPrimitive = 0;
    keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
    name = sortId;
};
sortIdValue =     {
    isPrimitive = 1;
    keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
    name = sortIdValue;
};
ticket =     {
    isPrimitive = 0;
    keyValueCodingClass = TSNTicketApiTO;
    name = ticket;
};
```

}
    2014-07-07 13:17:50.194 VZN Mobile[440:9f07] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:440 Found transformable value at keyPath '(null)'. Transforming from class '__NSCFNumber' to 'NSDecimalNumber'
    2014-07-07 13:17:50.204 VZN Mobile[440:9f07] self.object:10

Comment: Show your mapping and JSON which is causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Wain for the comment. Actually it was caused by a wrong code in Restkit transforming NSDecimalNumber to NSNumber. There is a method in RKValueTransformers.m:

```
+ (instancetype)decimalNumberToNumberValueTransformer
{
    ....
    ....
    RKValueTransformerTestOutputValueClassIsSubclassOfClass(outputValueClass, (@[ [NSNumber class], [NSDecimalNumber class]]), error);
    if ([inputValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        *outputValue = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[inputValue decimalValue]];
    } else if ([inputValue isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]]) {
        *outputValue = inputValue;
    }
    return YES;
}];
}
```

The conditions have to be swapped this way:

```
    if ([inputValue isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]]) {
        *outputValue = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[inputValue decimalValue]];
    } else if ([inputValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        *outputValue = inputValue;
    }
```

Then the code is not crashing and it is working as author originally assumed.

Comment: Your correction doesn't look fully correct / consistent (one branch returns `NSNumber` and the other returns `NSDecimalNumber`), and you should raise a bug report on github if you haven't already done so

Comment: You are right. That is something I also paused at. But I was satisfied as NSDecimalNumber is subclass of NSNumber.